# Kops kubenet cluster autoscaling not working

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kops

I have a kops cluster with a max of 75 nodes and added  with [cluster autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/cluster-autoscaler). It uses [kubenet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/networking.md#kops-default-networking) networking. 
Things have currently stopped working - ie scale down is no longer happening.

**The cluster is running on max capacity ie 75 nodes even with almost no load. Not sure where to start to troubleshoot the problem.**

See the following errors in the cluster autoscaler pod

```
    I0222 01:45:14.327164       1 static_autoscaler.go:97] Starting main loop
W0222 01:45:14.770818       1 static_autoscaler.go:150] Cluster is not ready for autoscaling
I0222 01:45:15.043126       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0222 01:45:17.121507       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0222 01:45:19.126665       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0222 01:45:21.327581       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0222 01:45:23.331802       1 leaderelection.go:199] successfully renewed lease kube-system/cluster-autoscaler
I0222 01:45:24.775124       1 static_autoscaler.go:97] Starting main loop
W0222 01:45:25.085442       1 static_autoscaler.go:150] Cluster is not ready for autoscaling
```

Autoscaling was working fine.

Update, also see the following errors when running `kops validate cluster`

```
    VALIDATION ERRORS
    KIND    NAME                MESSAGE
    Node    ip-172-20-32-173.ec2.internal   node "ip-172-20-32-173.ec2.internal" is not ready
 ...

I0221 22:16:02.688911    2403 node_conditions.go:60] node "ip-172-20-51-238.ec2.internal" not ready: &NodeCondition{Type:NetworkUnavailable,Status:True,LastHeartbeatTime:2019-02-21 22:15:56 -0500 EST,LastTransitionTime:2019-02-21 22:15:56 -0500 EST,Reason:NoRouteCreated,Message:RouteController failed to create a route,}
```

Comment: Can you grep log from cluster-autoscaler for `cannot be removed`? How are allocated resources looking on the nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was that my Cluster had gone into an Unhealthy state because of [this limitation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/networking.md#kops-default-networking) in AWS VPC routing tables.My cluster had scaled to 75 nodes and then had become unhealthy and was not able to scale down.

From the link,

> One important limitation when using kubenet networking is that an AWS routing table cannot have more than 50 entries, which sets a limit of 50 nodes per cluster.